# Get "uint" result from bitwise operators in AS?

Tags: actionscript-3, bit-manipulation

I am trying to figure out how to convert an RGB to an ARGB inline. If I put the result into a uint, it works, but if I try to use the value directly it treats it like an int, even if all the values are uints. Am I stuck with an extra assignment?

```
var test:uint = 0xCCCCCC |  (0xFF << 24);
trace(test.toString(16));
//ffcccccc

var rgb:uint = 0xCCCCCC;
var alpha:uint = 0xFF;
trace((rgb | (alpha << 24)).toString(16))
//-333334
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `uint((alpha << 24)).toString(16));`?

Answer (score 0):

That won't help. You just interpret result as uint, but AS performs shifting as int.

try this

```
trace(2147483648 >> 1); // -1073741824

trace(uint(2147483648 >> 1)); // 3221225472
```

All you need is using usigned bitwise shift operators like so:

```
trace(2147483648 >>> 1); // 1073741824
```